# data-ui-tinymce inside a modal dialog only populated when it is opened for the first time

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following code in a modal dialog box:

```
    <input data-ng-model="modal.formData.text" type="text">
    <textarea
        data-ui-tinymce
        data-ng-disabled="modal.action=='delete'"
        data-ng-model="modal.formData.text"
        id="inputText"
        required></textarea>
```

The dialog box is opened when a user clicks on a grid edit button inside a table of rows.

The first time (after a hard refresh) the user clicks edit then the `<input>` box and tinymce window are populated.  Subsequent clicks of edit open the dialog but only the `<input>` box is populated.

Comment: Hey Melina, is there a jsfiddle available for this? So I could have a proper look. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I spent the last three days trying to solve this problem and ended up ditching the angularjs directive for tinymce. I don't think its quite ready for prime-time. My work-around was to put this in the Angular-Bootstrap modal dialog box's controller:

```
    setTimeout(function() {   //wait for the dialog to be open
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#editorID",
            setup:function(ed) {
                ed.on("init", function(){
                    $scope.editor = ed; //save a reference to the editor
                    //manually put your model into the editor:
                    $scope.editor.setContent($scope.model.textForTheEditor); 
                });
            }   
        });
    }, 333); //a third of a second is more time than you need, but it works
```

And then when the dialog closes, update your model with the content of the editor:

```
   $scope.model.textForTheEditor = $scope.editor.getContent();
```

I know its not quite the solution you wanted and it violates the whole "no-DOM in the controller" paradigm, but it seems to be the only way to get TinyMCE to work repeatedly in the Anguler/Twitter Bootstrap dialog boxes.

I too would love a better solution using the Angularjs directive! Hope this helps.