# tinyMCE in an angularjs modal dialog only works on the first popup

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, tinymce-4

There is a modal box that is opened from the page multiple times. The tinyMCE control is initiated on the first popup but on subsequent popups, the `textarea` is not transformed.

I tried using a timer as suggested here [stackoverflow/17825282](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825282/data-ui-tinymce-inside-a-modal-dialog-only-populated-when-it-is-opened-for-the-f) but got the same result.

Code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HNvbqGGZYp8BH8GRMjmO?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce
Be sure not to set an id attribute.)

So just remove id:

```
    <textarea ui-tinymce="" ng-model="tinymceModel">{{SectionTemplate.Preface}}</textarea>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Mv2fLWuKiVjEIy77XNF0?p=preview